# To Wrap or Not To Wrap

Tags: c#, .net, class, wrapper

I guess it's a fairly subjective question so I'll site a specific example.

While considering the design of a set of wrapper classes to wrap access to WMI information using the `System.Management` namespace I had an issue where I started to wonder how I could cater to situations where a one-off value was needed, say the BIOS serial number from `Win32_BIOS`, and also to situations where many different properties might be needed or more complex searches, for example searching for files in `CIM_DataFile`.

This lead me to wonder if it is even a good idea to wrap functionality like that presented in the System.Management namespace, or whether in the end I will add unnecessarily complex and lengthy wrapper classes in the name of reducing the amount of code in an application.

What is the general consensus with this kind of problem, is it worth while writing complex wrapper classes in the hope of saving time later on or is it better to just stick with the flexibility of the built-in classes even if it sometimes doesn't seem especially clean or tidy.

Comment: Do you care about being able to mock the classes you're wrapping? If so, then yes.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would consider a wrapper for the .NET class (which in this case is a wrapper itself, I believe) only if I found myself writing the same code over and over again in multiple places in my application.  Clean, elegant code is a great goal and standard - but it's not worth it (IMO) if it comes at the cost of complexity, understandability and maintainability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a wrapper class is to hide complex functionality from the caller.

In other words, if all the calling application wants to do is find out the serial number then it should just call something like `myobj.GetSerialNumber()` which would make all of the WMI calls necessary to return that value.

However, if the calling application is already knee deep into WMI OR if you find yourself mimicking how the WMI stuff works with only minor changes then it's better to not wrap it and let the calling application do its thing.

Comment: I find this makes a lot of sense to me, but when I do it I start thinking I should really make such wrappers into re-usable libraries and the complexity snowballs from there.

Comment: @Ashigore: A given code base should only be as complex as necessary to solve the problem you are faced with.  In other words, make it only as reusable as necessary to solve your current problem.  If, at a later time, you find that your code could be reused in another application THEN you refactor it.  There are actually rare situations in which initially building for reuse works out... namely when you already have multiple systems, with specs you are aware of, are going to take advantage.

Comment: The primary reason I say this is that you have absolutely NO idea what the requirements are for any future systems.  Because of this, you have absolutely NO idea what features they may need.  Which means no matter what, you'll be refactoring your library anyway.  Better to keep it simple now and introduce complexity only when actually necessary; and even then only introduce the amount of complexity required.

Comment: Yes, this does make sense, saves wasting time wrapping functionality I don't even need. Thank you.